# Screen flickers; remove and insert sounds play; mouse moves to the center of the screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, display, mouse

I recently re-installed Windows 10 on my desktop computer after my previous Windows 10 install stopped working (would no longer boot). Since then, I have encountered a strange problem. This problem would first only occur after Windows started, but has increased in frequency to the point that it is now happening every few seconds. The following happen simultaneously:

- The screen flickers; the duration ranges from nearly imperceptible to half a second.
- The remove and insert sounds play (in that order) (the ones that play when you remove or insert a USB device).
- The mouse cursor moves to the center of the screen (if I'm moving the mouse, this doesn't always happen, and clicking on something will sometimes delay it).

I have tried, to no change:

- Unplugging the second monitor.
- Unplugging the mouse.
- Restarting the computer.
- A Windows Defender virusscan (found nothing).
- Malwarebytes Free scan (aside from the expected erroneous detection of the installer for DGVoodoo, a widely-used tool for emulating the 3Dfx Voodoo graphics card API, it found nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Partially solved; it is caused by my Oculus Rift DK2 repeatedly turning itself off and on. As such, this question is no longer appropriate for this stack exchange and can be considered closed.

Comment: Not sure I agree with you here. You indeed solved it, but it is definitely one of those cases that someone else could also experience and they're pulling their hair out. In a last attempt to solve it, they google, find this answer and finally get pushed into a direction that allows them to solve it. So +1 to encourage you to mark it solved rather than deleting the question.